# Powershell Get-ChildItem -Filter '*.txt' also finds '*.txt~' (too greedy?)

Tags: powershell, get-childitem

I'm on Windows 11 with Powershell vesrion 5.1.22621.963.

I want to list the contents of a directory while filtering on files ending in ".txt". I try the following:

```
> ls -Filter "*.txt"


    Directory: C:\so_example


Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
-a----          3/3/2023  11:25 AM              0 example.txt
-a----          3/3/2023  11:25 AM              0 example.txt~
```

But that also finds files that end in ".txt~" with a tilde, '~', as the last character. Those are backup files added by my text editor. I can remove them, but it gets pretty tedious if I have a large directory with many backup files.

What's going on here? Why is the tilde being matched? How can I stop it from being matched?

I tried forming a search expression that will match only to the end of "txt", like this:

```
> ls -Filter "*.txt$"
```

But this returns no results (in the same directory as above).

Comment: Cannot reproduce.. (I'm on Windows 10, PowerShell 5.1)

Comment: Cannot reproduce on Windows 10 either. Is `ls -Filter "*.txt"` the only command you run? Because PowerShell in some cases merges table output of multiple commands and you might see "example.txt~" from a previous command.

Comment: @theo, @zett42, you might be using `pwsh` instead of `powershell`. This issue was fixed in NET core and subsequently doesn't carry over into PowerShell Core,

Comment: I think in 5.1 it can match the short version of the names seen with `cmd /c dir /x`

Comment: Use -B option which will ignore backups.  Read the manual : man ls

Comment: The workaround for this in windows pwsh is to use `-Include *.txt` or simply `\*.txt` in the path unfortunately. Luckily it was fixed in dotnet core

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an anomaly of the [.NET API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.enumeratefiles?view=net-7.0):

> When you use the asterisk wildcard character in searchPattern and you specify a three-character file extension, for example, "*.txt", this method also returns files with extensions that begin with the specified extension.

There is a workaround, but it includes a limitation of the search string. If you don't use the start but instead a row of questions marks, you get the expected result:

```
Get-Child-Item -Filter '??????????????????.txt'
```

Limitation: If the number of `?` is too small you get less file names.

[1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.enumeratefiles?view=net-7.0)https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.enumeratefiles?view=net-7.0

Comment: Thanks. It seems "?" is interpreted as a non-greedy, any-character match. So, for example,if I enter `ls -Filter ???????.txt` (seven ?'s) I only get back  the "example.txt" file, but if I enter `ls -Filter ????????.txt` (8 ?'s) I get back both files (edit: "example" has seven characters).